# Magento 1, compiler gives 500 on disabled products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, compiler

We have a pretty weird issue, if we enable the php compiler disabled products will return a 500 page. If we enable php errors using `php_ini` it returns a 200 but the page contains nothing.

In the logs there is nothing. No error is being logged, the only thing that shows up is the request in the access.log

```
{
"time":"2018-03-01T09:58:10+00:00",
"remote_addr":"172.28.128.1",
"remote_user":"-",
"host":"sitename",
"request":"GET /nl/5-gram-goud-baar-perth HTTP/1.1",
"status":"500",
"body_bytes_sent":"5",
"referer":"-",
"user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0",
"request_time":"0.136",
"handler":"phpfpm",
"country":"-",
"port":"80",
"ssl_cipher":"-",
"ssl_protocol":"-"
}
```

All I have managed to find out is that it crashes at a low-level as it won't reach the view, won't reach the block, won't reach the layout.

The server is running Nginx, on a Hypernode box. And magento 1.9.2.2